# About motivation of Lang's Proof $S_n$ is not solvable for $n\geq 5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

In Lang, he proves that $S_n$ is not solvable if $n\geq 5$ by using following observation.

If $N\unlhd H\leq G$, $H$ contains every $3$-cycle, and if $H/N$ is abelian, then $H$ contains every $3$-cycle.

Where is this observation coming from? Why $3$-cycle, not $2$-cycle or some other $m$-cycle?

Comment: The 3-cycles generate $A_n$, so it's natural to consider them when you're trying to analyze the normal subgroups of $S_n$. As soon as you have all the 3-cycles in a subgroup of $S_n$ then you have at least half the group in your subgroup.

Comment: Keep in mind that nonsolvability of $S_n$ is a consequence of something much stronger which is being proved by this argument: namely that $A_n$ is the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ and that $A_n$ is a simple group.

Comment: @LeeMosher: What do refer to with "proved by this argument"? Do you speak about the proof given by Lang or about the observation mentioned in the question?